# Sending a redirect with code 401 from Flask doesn't redirect

Tags: python, http, redirect, flask

When i do this, it work:

```
return redirect('/admin-login')
```

But when I try to pass a http code in parameter, the redirection dont work and I get to this page:`

```
return redirect('/admin-login', code=401)
```

> Redirecting...
>
> You should be redirected automatically to target URL: /admin-login. If
>   not click the link.

How do I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is actually *there* in both cases. Flask uses the [`Location`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) header field to trigger a redirect. So when your browser sees that it skips displaying the content and immediately redirects.

The reason it doesn't work for `code=401`, is because `401 Unauthorized` is a client error. This results in the browser ignoring the redirect (at least with Chrome).

The Flask documentation for [`flask.redirect`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.redirect) mentions the following:

> Supported codes are 301, 302, 303, 305, and 307.

It doesn't specifically mention why they are the only supported ones. But the best assumption is because browsers generally *shouldn't* redirect if it's not a [3XX status code (Redirection)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection).

The solution is thus to use one of the supported status codes.

Comment: Thanks you for the help

Answer (score 2):

Solution that worked for me:

```
@app.errorhandler(401)
def page_not_found(e):
    return redirect('http://example.com')
```

previously I had been trying:

```
@app.errorhandler(401)
def page_not_found(e):
    return redirect('http://example.com', code=401)
```

...but it turns out the ", code=401" specification is not needed if it's up in errorhandler, and without it, it automatically redirects.

Answer (score 1):

my solution was to create custom error pages, adding the redirect meta to the header. This will force the page to be redirected to the homepage after 5 seconds of the page being open =}

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=/" />
```